# How can I make this simple function work?

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;



contract P{
    uint no1;
    uint no2;
    uint result;

function MultEvensAddOdds(uint _no1, uint _no2) public pure returns(uint) {
    result public myresult = result;
    if(_no1 % 2 == 0 && _no2 % 2 == 0){
        uint myresult = _no1 + _no2;
    }else if(_no1 % 2 == 1 && _no2 % 2 == 1){
        uint myresult = _no1 * _no2;
    }else{
        uint myresult = _no1/_no2;
    }
}
```

}

I want to Multiple two even numbers, add two odd numbers, or divide both numbers if none of the previous conditions are met.
However I am getting this error:
ParserError: Expected ';' but got 'public'
result public myresult = result;
^----^

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
result public myresult = result;
```

You must to declare a new variable in this way:

```
[datatype] [variableName] = [value];
```

In your case you change this line in this way:

```
uint myresult = result;
```

And then use `myresult` variable to set operation results. You can see this smart contract code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract P{
    uint no1;
    uint no2;
    uint result;

    function MultEvensAddOdds(uint _no1, uint _no2) public view returns(uint) {
        uint myresult = result;
        if(_no1 % 2 == 0 && _no2 % 2 == 0){
            myresult = _no1 + _no2;
        }else if(_no1 % 2 == 1 && _no2 % 2 == 1){
            myresult = _no1 * _no2;
        }else{
            myresult = _no1 / _no2;
        }
        return myresult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess this way "result public myresult = result;" is only applicable for structs if I am not wrong. Anyways, I am using remix IDE, I can not see the output when I input my values at the deployed contract

Comment: Yes, you can use that statement that you declared in your original smart contract code for struct (but it's different for this operation the initialization). However I updated my answer, for view the result of MultEvensAddOdds function only adding the 'view' keyword into signature method and specify 'return [variable]'.

Comment: I see, however, the output for whatever number I input is "0:
uint256: 0".

There are also tons of warnings "This declaration shadows an existing declaration" and "Unused local variable."

Comment: I cannot see these warnings. Did you try to copy and paste the code in my answer into Remix IDE? Moreover, I tried your MultEvensAddOdds function in my smart contract code and works.

Comment: Oh I figured out a few things, the code we both typed has a silly mistake, basically, the conditions should be the way around (i.e. * not + for the 1st condition) and my code is not working properly because I typed uint before myresult at each conditional statement (I wonder why tho).